# roots of the polynomial equations and relation among the coefficients

Tags: polynomials, roots

If the equation $x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + 1 = 0$ ($a,b,c$ are real numbers) has no real roots and if at least one root is of modulus one, then what is the relation between $a,b$ and $c$?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: first prove that all the roots have modulus $1$.  Then consider the reciprocal polynomial.

Comment: Could you please explain with more details?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial

Answer (score 4):

As the roots come in pairs of complex conjugates and the constant part is their product, we see that *all* roots have modulus $1$.

As a consequence some more estimates can be found such as $-2<a<2$.

Comment: What about the polynomial $x^4-3x^3+4.25x^2-3x+1$?

Answer (score 3):

Factoring $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+1=(x^2+dx+1)(x^2+ex+1)$ shows that $a=c=d+e$ and $b=2+de$.  To require no real roots we have the inequalities $-2<d,e<2$.  Hence all possible triplets $(a,b,c)$ have the form:

$$(a,b,c)=(d+e,2+de,d+e)$$

for some $(d,e)\in(-2,2)\times (-2,2)$.

Intuitively, $d$ is twice the real part of one pair of complex roots, $z,\bar{z}$.  Since $|z|=1$, and $z\ne\bar{z}$, it follows that $-1<\operatorname{Re}z<1$, which gives us our inequalities for $d$.  Similarly for $e$.